# How to get specific part of the string using sscanf function?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a problem reading users input correctly.

User types `"A Smaug 23 fire 10"` and I need to get the all the information to my code except the first letter `'A'`.

```
char buffer[80];
char *ret = fgets(buffer, 80, stdin)
if (ret == NULL){
     break;
}
char name[10],weapon[10];
int attackpoints, hitpoints;
int x = sscanf(ret," %s %d %s %d", name, &attackpoints,weapon,&hitpoints);
```

This won't work.

How can I skip the `A` and store users input to the right variables like `name = Smaug`, `attackpoints = 23`, `weapon = fire`, etc?

Comment: Like this `int x = sscanf(ret," %*s %s %d %s %d", name, &attackpoints, weapon, &hitpoints);` where the first specifier with a `*` reads but ignores (several) chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the string `A[2]` for the first letter. Read all string and print all of value expect `A`:

```
char A[2], name[10],weapon[10];
int x = sscanf(ret,"%s %s %d %s %d", A, name, &attackpoints,weapon,&hitpoints);
```

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[80];
    char *ret = fgets(buffer, 80, stdin);
    if (ret == NULL)
         exit(-1);
    char A[2], name[10],weapon[10];
    int attackpoints, hitpoints;
    int x = sscanf(ret,"%s %s %d %s %d", A, name, &attackpoints,weapon,&hitpoints);
    if (x != 5)
        exit(-1);
    printf("name = %s, attackpoints = %d, weapon = %s, hitpoints = %d\n", name, attackpoints, weapon, hitpoints);
    return 0;
}
```

The input and ouput:

```
./test 
A Smaug 23 fire 10
name = Smaug, attackpoints = 23, weapon = fire, hitpoints = 10
```

Comment: Okay, I thought it could be done some other way but that is good also.

Comment: @konde020202: It *could* be done another way, e.g. by having a literal `"A "` at the start of your scanf format string that the input has to match before scanf will move on to later conversions.  See the docs, e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf which mention literal non-whitespace characters.